# Lambda function to display year fraction between today and a date t

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a lambda function to my DF in order to add a new column. In it, years fraction should be added.

I did try the following :

```
DF['YEAR_FRAC']  = DF['YEAR_FRAC'].apply(lambda x: datetime.now() - x.DATE_Col/timedelta(days=365))
```

but this does throw the following error :

```
KeyError: 'YEAR_FRAC'
```

and

```
DF['YEAR_FRAC']  = DF.apply(lambda x: datetime.now() - x.DATE_Col/timedelta(days=365))
```

throw :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'DATE_Col'
```

DF looks like :

| DATE_Col |
| --- |
| 2045-02-15 00:00:00 |
| 2037-03-15 00:00:00 |
| NaT |
| 2030-02-15 00:00:00 |

If the error is throw by `NaT` values, then how do I handle these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF['YEAR_FRAC']  = DF['DATE_Col'].apply(lambda x: datetime.now() - x/timedelta(days=365))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'DATE_Col'